# Why do I get a segmentation error?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have this code, which is part of a library for handing a database (as a linked list):

```
char *db_getVal(char *key, Node *database) { 
    while(database != NULL){
        if(strcmp(key, database->key) == 0){ 
            return database->value;
        }else{
            database = database->next;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

It works fine when I use a key that exists in database, but when I enter a key that does not, I get a segmentation fault. Why is that?

Comment: There are several possibilities. On which line do you get the segfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the last element's `next` member is set to `NULL`. If it's not explicitly set, it might be some junk value that's not `NULL` but nevertheless will cause your program to receive a segmentation fault if accessed.

Comment: Can I do that directly in the struct definition? Like: typedef struct database { struct database *next = NULL; } *Database;

Comment: @theva: No. It has to be done explicitly after the memory for it has been allocated.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the database link, make sure its last item database->next set to null